# Generate soap message from classes in ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a lots of class which contains the data i want to sent to server & I want to generate dynamic soapMessage based on the class how can I do that ?

I am using below function to get soapMessage for simple message,

```
func generateSoapMsgBody<T>(a: T)->String{

    let classObject = a


    //to get class name
    var className=reflect(classObject).summary.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!


    var test = GetAirports()


    var opTag = "<\(className)>"

    var count = reflect(classObject).count

    for var index = 0;index<count ;++index{


        var varName = reflect(classObject)[index].0
        var value = reflect(classObject)[index].1.value

        opTag += "<\(varName)>\(value)</\(varName)>"


        }



    opTag += "</\(className)>"
    }
```

How can i generate message for complex  type with nested arrays & nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, with SOAP web APIs, I've found it simplest to do the following:

1. Create a template XML with appropriate substitution variable "holes". I normally put these templates as a resource
2. Load the templates into memory, and substitute the variables as needed
3. POST this string to the SOAP service

For example, if you have the following XML in your project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelop ...>
  <soap:Body>
    <A>%@</A>
    <B>%@</B>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelop>
```

Then you load it using `NSBundle` and `pathForResource`, and after retrieving the `NSString` from the resource, you use `.format` to substitute the `%@` in the resource with your class variables.

This gives you the string you need to POST to the SOAP service.

I have found this to be the most flexible, the easiest to unit test, and the simplest to get started with consuming a SOAP service outside of using C#/wsdl/soap proxy generators.